# How to scrollTop using a variable for px?

Tags: jquery

Since I am using ajax to load content inside a container, I first of all check if the body has a class, if it doesn't add it and if it does I want the window to scroll to the newly added content. The distance that i want it to scroll needs to be the height of the container which I set with a global var at the beginning. The timer is just to make sure all content is fully loaded before to set the variable. 185 is an extra amount of px I need as the header has that height.

it is working but it is not scrolling at the exact misure

First html load

```
<div class="loadedList"> --- First time we save its height+header height in a globalVar pos
   <div class="ajax-wrapper">
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Second html when new content is loaded

```
<div class="loadedList">
   <div class="ajax-wrapper">
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
   </div>
   <div class="ajax-wrapper"> -- Scroll to this very top which should be pos variable
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
      <div class="item></div>
   </div>
</div>

if (!jQuery("body").hasClass("loadedList")) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("body").addClass("loadedList");
        pos = jQuery("#list").outerHeight() + 185;
    }, 2000);
}
else {
    $("body, html").animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    }, 1000).offset().top;
}
```

Comment: You can start by removing `"+="` and `"px"`, which are not needed.

Comment: ok thanks but yet how to scrollTo pos value ?

Comment: You do not need the height of new content to scroll down, just scroll down to the existing content bottom (header height + existing content height).

Comment: is it not what I am doing?

Comment: I do not see where and when you insert new content, you better add some dummy html. You should insert html after you make calculations above.

Comment: question edited with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what made it work

```
        if(!jQuery("body").hasClass("loadedList")) {
                jQuery("body").addClass("loadedList");
        } else {
        var pos = jQuery("#list").height();
        $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000).offset().top;
    }
```